# Graalvm generated binary is working inside the project directory but not outside that directory

Tags: java, java-8, executable-jar, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I am using a rather simple Java application that receives an input file, process it and generate an output file. I am using `Picocli` for arguments to the application and `Graalvm` to create a native binary.
I first created the `artifact` in intellij including the libraries and specifying the class containing the main method, I then used `build artifact` option to build the jar file. After that, I used the following command to create the binary

```
native-image -jar metadata-processor.jar
```

The jar and binary are created inside the project as `projectName/out/artifacts/app_jar` I can run the binary using

```
./binary -i abc -o xyz
```

I can run the jar file using

```
java -jar binary.jar -i abc -o xyz
```

However when I move the `binary` to `~Download` directory and run the same above command I get the error

```
./binary -i abc -o xyz
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
```

The jar is still working though i.e.

```
java -jar binary.jar -i abc -o xyz
```

If I create a simple hello world program and create a binary then it works fine even if I move it to another folder so it seems to be a library issue or project structure.

Please let me know if some special step is required in the case of libraries.

Comment: It looks like native-image is failing to generate a binary and is falling back to JVM-mode. Try compiling with `--no-fallback` and the build will probably fail.

Comment: @zakkak yes it failed with some type error `Error: type is not available in this platform: org.graalvm.nativeimage.impl.ImageSingletonsSupport`

Comment: Is it because of the mac m1 max or some other issue?

Comment: I am not sure to be honest. Better update the github issue and provide more info there (like the full stack trace).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, finally, what worked for me is to create the configuration file. It becomes a two-step process

Step 1:

First I create a jar file of the project using intellij then I run the jar file to create a configuration file of the project in META_INF/native-image directory using `-agentlib:native-image-agent` i.e.

```
java -agentlib:native-image-agent=config-output-dir=/Users/mianahmad/goldeneye/json-processor/src/main/resources/META-INF/native-image -jar metadata-processor.jar -i /Users/mianahmad/goldeneye/json-processor/input/Claimant.json -o /Users/mianahmad/goldeneye/json-processor/output/Claimant_output.json
```

Step 2:

After that I created a jar again and then created the native image.

```
native-image -jar app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

After that, I moved the project to another location using

```
mv app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies /Users/mianahmad/Desktop
```

Run the binary and viola it is still working

```
./app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies
```